# Asymptotic to $f( 2 f^{[-1]}(x) ) $?

Tags: optimization, asymptotics, dynamical-systems, tetration

Let $f(x)$ be the half-iterate of $ 2 sinh(x).$

Im looking for an asymptotic to $f( 2 f^{[-1]}(x))$ for Large $x>0$. $^{[*]}$ means iteration here thus $^{[-1]}$ means functional inverse.

---

For the $y$ th iteration of $ 2 sinh(x) $ we use the fixpoint at $0$ And use the so-called koenigs function. Also we use analytic continuation.

See

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenigs_function

---

Let O be big-oh notation.
I think the approximation below makes sense

$$ f( 2 f^{[-1]} (x) ) = O ( x * 2sinh^{[A]}(x) ) $$

For some real $A>0$ ??

What is the best fit value for $A$ ?

Comment: Hmm, just to see whether I'm on the right track: I've constructed the powerseries for $f(x)$ where $f(f(x))=2 \text{sinh}(x) $ , $g(x) = f^{[-1]}(x) $ and $h(x) = f( 2\cdot g(x))$ , see the found powerseries in the image (coefficients to be read in columns, just the first 8 terms are shown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaTq1.png . Is this correct so far?

Comment: @Gottfried yes that seems correct.

Comment: Btw this occured somewhere on the tetration forum. But I can not find it. I know it was posted by Tommy1729 and also that it got no replies by others. Apart from the trivial fact that it grows slower than any $x^a$ for $a>1$ no results were posted.

Comment: I have a solution. Will post later.

Answer (score 1):

$f(f(x))=2sh(x)$ and let put $A=f(2f^{-1}(x))$

If $y=f^{-1}(x)$ then $f(x)=2sh(y)$ and $f^{-1}(x)=argsh(\frac{f(x)}{2})$

Thus $f(A)=2sh(2argsh(\frac{f(x)}{2}))$ and reporting in $f^{-1}$ formula

$A=argsh(f(2sh(2argsh(\frac{f(x)}{2}))/2)$

So if we suppose $\lim \limits_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=+\infty$ we can use $argsh(\frac{u}{2})\sim\ln(u)$ and  $2sh(u)\sim e^u$

$A\sim \ln(f(2sh(2\ln(f(x))))\sim \ln(f(e^{2\ln(f(x)}))\sim \ln(f(f(x)^2)$

All this is not very rigourous, but I suppose that if you know some equivalent for $f$ in $+\infty$ then you can conclude easily. I'm not familiar enough with half-iterate of $sh$ to go further.

Comment: I upvoted this. Yet the real problem is that this appears as the start of circular reasoning. When we try to simplify the last expression we end Up with the original question naturally. Looks like a catch 22 situation , and that is funny since there are (also as in 22 ) two 2's in the equations !! :)

Comment: We can show $A(x) > 2x$ for sufficiently Large $x$. But that is far away from our goal.

Comment: The issue is that we don't know much about the half-iterate, we don't even know if it goes $\to +\infty$ in $+\infty$. For instance consider the simple half-iterates of $x$ which are $-x$ and $1/x$ they don't have the same behaviour at all. Regarding your other question on the same subject, you considered a particular power serie as the half-iterate, but who knows how many other choices there are. I assumed one that was growing to infinity and got some result, but I agree it is not very satisfying :p

Comment: I intend the solution we get from using the fixpoint at 0. Koenigs function can then be used. Should probably add that in the OP. Your asssumption was correct and natural ; since any other interpretation gives problems like you mentioned.